# In C# how do access my LINQ var array from another method?

Tags: c#, linq

I am using LINQ to create tables in a WPF application, but when I try to access one of those tables using an event method, my compiler tells me "The name 'parts' does not exist in the current context". Is there something I should do to adjust the scope so that I can access a var from a separate method?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace FinalExam_SupplierPartsWPF
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var suppliers = new[] {
            new{SN = 1, SName = "Smith", Status = 20, City="London"},
            new{SN = 2, SName = "Jones", Status = 10, City="Paris"},
            new{SN = 3, SName = "Blake", Status = 30, City="Paris"},
            new{SN = 4, SName = "Clark", Status = 20, City="London"},
            new{SN = 5, SName = "Adams", Status = 30, City="Athens"}
        };

        var parts = new[] {
            new{PN = 1, PName="Nut", Color = "Red", Weight = 12, City="London"},
            new{PN = 2, PName="Bolt", Color = "Green", Weight = 17, City="Paris"},
            new{PN = 3, PName="Screw", Color = "Blue", Weight = 17, City="Rome"},
            new{PN = 4, PName="Screw", Color = "Red", Weight = 14, City="London"},
            new{PN = 5, PName="Cam", Color = "Blue", Weight = 12, City="Paris"},
            new{PN = 6, PName="Cog", Color = "Red", Weight = 19, City="London"}
        };

        var shipment = new[] {
            new{SN = 1, PN = 1, Qty=300},
            new{SN = 1, PN = 2, Qty=200},
            new{SN = 1, PN = 3, Qty=400},
            new{SN = 1, PN = 4, Qty=200},
            new{SN = 1, PN = 5, Qty=100},
            new{SN = 1, PN = 6, Qty=100},
            new{SN = 2, PN = 1, Qty=300},
            new{SN = 2, PN = 2, Qty=400},
            new{SN = 3, PN = 2, Qty=200},
            new{SN = 4, PN = 2, Qty=200},
            new{SN = 4, PN = 4, Qty=300},
            new{SN = 4, PN = 5, Qty=400}
        };

        IEnumerable<string> colorList = parts
            .OrderBy(part => part.Color)
            .Select(part => part.Color)
            .Distinct();

        foreach (string x in colorList)
            cbxColorSelect.Items.Add(x);

    }

    private void ColorSelectedEvent(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        lbxPartDisplay.Items.Add("test");
        string colorChoice = cbxColorSelect.Text;

        IEnumerable<string> partResults = parts
            .Where(clr => String.Equals(clr.Color, colorChoice))
            .Select(part => String.Format("{0}", part.PName));

        foreach (string y in partResults)
            lbxPartDisplay.Items.Add(y);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This has nothing to do with LINQ - it's basic C#. You can't access the local variables of one method from another. The `MainWindow` constructor has  completed by the time `ColorSelectedEvent` runs... the variable is long gone. If you need to keep it, you'll need it to be a field rather than a local variable. I would strongly recommend that you learn the basics of C# with console apps before moving onto GUIs - there are a lot fewer moving parts to worrying about that way.

Answer (score 1):

The `parts`, `suppliers` and `shipments` variables are declared in the scope of the `MainWindow()` method; they will not be accessible anywhere outside of this method.  If you want to access these variables in another method within the same class, you should declare them as private to the class.

When a variable is declared, you typically specify an access modifier.  In your example, you are creating the variables implicitly using the `var` keyword.  Variables created in such a manner have a default access modifier of `private`. This means that they are scoped to they containing block in which they are created, which in your case is the `MainWindow()` method.  As others have suggested, I would recommend a review of variable scope and access modifiers. You will need to have a solid grasp of these basics to be productive.

Check out [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C-Sharp-Fundamentals-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners) channel 9 video series on some C# fundamentals for beginners; specifically, episode 5 focuses on variables. [This](http://www.codecandle.com/articles/csharp/variables/variable-scope.html) blog post also goes over some basics on variable scope.

The `var` keyword used for variable declaration means that the variable is implicitly defined based on the assignment.  What this means is that the compiler will look at what you are assigning to the variable (ie: what is on the right side of the equals sign) and figure out the type.  For [technical reasons](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields.aspx), you cannot use the `var` declaration operator for variables defined at the class level (also often referred to as 'fields' of a class if they are private to the class).

Since you cannot use the `var` keyword to define your class level variables, you must explicitly specify a type.  In the example below, I have created a class which represents the original `parts` anonymous type you were working with in your example.

I also concur with the advice of other on starting out learning C# using a console application.  GUI applications bring a lot of other nuances to the table which can only serve to confuse you and cause general frustration when you are learning a language.  For example: simple things such as [updating a textbox from the non GUI thread](http://nnish.com/2010/03/14/accessing-wpf-controls-on-a-non-ui-thread/)  with a new value can bomb your program and leave you wondering why it doesn't work.

You can choose to continue to work with an array of anonymous types, however you would need to declare it as `dynamic` or `object`.  Working with an array of anonymous objects can be a little more challenging. I would recommend that you use a defined type (such as the one `part` class have illustrated below) for your class fields.

for example:

```
public class Part
{
    public int PN { get; set; }
    public String PName { get; set; }
    public String Color { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public String City { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    private List<Part> _parts;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _parts.Add(new Part() { PN = 1, PName = "Nut", Color = "Red", Weight = 12, City = "London" });
        _parts.Add(new Part() { PN = 2, PName = "Bolt", Color = "Green", Weight = 17, City = "Paris" });
        _parts.Add(new Part() { PN = 3, PName = "Screw", Color = "Blue", Weight = 17, City = "Rome" });
        _parts.Add(new Part() { PN = 4, PName = "Screw", Color = "Red", Weight = 14, City = "London" });
        _parts.Add(new Part() { PN = 5, PName = "Cam", Color = "Blue", Weight = 12, City = "Paris" });
        _parts.Add(new Part() { PN = 6, PName = "Cog", Color = "Red", Weight = 19, City = "London" });

    }

    private void SomeMethod()
    {
        string colorChoice = "Blue";

        IEnumerable<string> partResults = _parts
            .Where(clr => String.Equals(clr.Color, colorChoice))
            .Select(part => String.Format("{0}", part.PName));
    }
}
```

Comment: When I try to add it outside of MainWindow() as you did I get the compiler error "The type or namespace 'var' could not be found"

Comment: @shampouya: please read some basic documentation. You can't use `var` for class member definitions.

Comment: @shampouya: I have updated my answer to hopefully provide you some additional details on the usage of `var`, variable declarations and scope.  I wish you well learning they C# language.